# return different value from a before do block in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

is there a way to stop execution and return a different value in a before do block in sinatra ?

```
before do
   # code is here
   # I would like to 'return "Message"'
   # I would like "/home" to not get called.
end



// rest of the code

get '/home' do

end
```

Answer (score 9):

```
before do
  halt 401, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, 'Message!'
end
```

You can specify only status if you want, here's example with status, headers and body

Answer (score 2):

On http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro Filters section

> Before filters are evaluated before
>   each request within the context of the
>   request and can modify the request and
>   response. Instance variables set in
>   filters are accessible by routes and
>   templates:

```
  before do
    @note = 'Hi!'
    request.path_info = '/foo/bar/baz'
  end

  get '/foo/*' do
    @note #=> 'Hi!'
    params[:splat] #=> 'bar/baz'
  end
```

Comment: does this mean if I reset request.path_info to a different value, the route will change ?